# mongodb query to get documents which match an element inside an array and should not match elements inside another array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hello I have products table and it's data as given below

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6ad"), 
"type" : "product", 
"product_name" : "product1", 
"created_date" : "2016-10-06 19:36:30", 
"display_areas" : [
    {
        "area" : "area1", 
        "order" : "11", 
        "price" : 10.0
    }, 
    {
        "area" : "area2", 
        "order" : "11", 
        "valid" : 11.0
    }
], 
"user_deleted" : [
    {
        "area" : "area1", 
        "user" : "user1"
    }, 
    {
        "area" : "area1", 
        "user" : "user2"
    }
]
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6ad"), 
"type" : "product", 
"product_name" : "product2", 
"created_date" : "2016-10-06 19:36:30", 
"display_areas" : [
    {
        "area" : "area1", 
        "order" : "11", 
        "price" : 10.0
    }, 
    {
        "area" : "area2", 
        "order" : "11", 
        "valid" : 11.0
    }
]
}
```

In general I want to display these products based on the display_areas and I can do that query easily with unwind option. But I want to display them to a particular user based on display_areas which are not deleted by user.

In the example above If I have to display products for user1 in area1 I should get the information of product2 only. Because, user1 deleted the area1 for product1.

Is this the best database structure for this kind of query? I am open to any suggestions regarding the structure too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea that comes to mind. You can move the `user` into `users` array inside the `display_areas` array and remove the `user_deleted` array. So your new structure for `product1` will look like below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5870f1d9dd0ef6e62102e6ad"),
    "type": "product",
    "product_name": "product1",
    "created_date": "2016-10-06 19:36:30",
    "display_areas": [{
        "area": "area1",
        "order": "11",
        "price": 10.0,
        "users" : ["user1", "user2"]
    }, {
        "area": "area2",
        "order": "11",
        "valid": 11.0
    }]
}
```

Now can easily query the structure by using `elemMatch`. Something like this.

```
db.collection.find({"display_areas":{"$elemMatch":{"area": "area1", "users":{$ne:"user1"}}}})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the structure to what you suggested and the query also worked fine.